# How much of an advantage does it give to draw all 2 blank tiles and/or 4 S tiles in Scrabble?

Tags: scrabble, words-with-friends

I'm playing against someone who I've had close games with, but now they're up 110 points in a game (they have 420, I have 310) where they drew all the S's and blank tiles. I wonder if this is a coincidence or drawing those tiles have a significant advantage like on average being worth a certain amount of points or additional score.

According to the answer here, a blank tile is worth 25 points to an advanced player: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/31913/26603

How about S's worth, and combined with drawing all blank tiles?

Comment: A "certain" amount? no. But the ballpark is: you already have 50 (two blanks), so then it's just a matter of adding the four esses. And then factoring in all the other variables (going first, etc.) I'd say it's unlikely the four esses amount to the other 60 points, but it's not a science. There's no one true answer.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I'm looking for "on average". In the other case, it seems on average 25 points per blank tile for a good player. Wonder what would be the case on average for blanks + 4 S's

Comment: "2 blanks and 4 esses" is uncommon enough that not enough statistics are available to make a statement of average beyond the level of guess.